# How to find the range of values for this absolute value function?

Tags: parametric-functions

The function is：

```
f[x_] := Abs[2 x - k] + Abs[2/k x + 1/k^2]
```

The range of parameter k is:

```
0 < k <= 1
```

How to find the range of the function, the result contains the parameter k

I didn't get the desired result using the following code

```
f[x_] := Abs[2 x - k] + Abs[2/k x + 1/k^2]
FunctionRange[{f[x], 0 < k <= 1}, x, y]
```

The correct answer is:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

```
Reduce[FunctionRange[{f[x], 0 < k <= 1}, x, y]] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] := Abs[2 x - k] + Abs[2/k x + 1/k^2];
```

Same as @cvgmt, but uses *dom* as $\mathbb{R}$:

```
FunctionRange[{f[x], 0 < k <= 1}, x, y] // 
  Reduce[#, {x, y}, Reals] & // Expand
```

> 0 < k <= 1 && y >= 1/k + k

Comment: There is a question: why can the value range of this function be equal to k+1/k?

Comment: @csn899 - Evaluate `And @@ Table[k + 1/k == MinValue[f[x], x], {k, 1/100, 1, 1/100}]`

Answer (score 4):

Another way is as follows. We obtain the lower end of the range by

```
Minimize[{Abs[2 x - k] + Abs[2/k x + 1/k^2], k > 0 && k <= 1}, x][[1]]//FullSimplify
```

> `Piecewise[{{k^(-1) + k, Inequality[0,  Less, k, LessEqual, 1]}}, Infinity]`

It remains to notice `Abs[2 x - k] + Abs[2/k x + 1/k^2]` tends to infinity as `x` tends to infinity and defines a continuous function.

Comment: There is a question: why can the value range of this function be equal to k+1/k?

Comment: @ccsn899:  See the last two lines of my edited answer and the result of `Minimize[{Abs[2 x - k] + Abs[2/k x + 1/k^2], k > 0 && k <= 1}, x]`.